# How can I use Show,Hide, and Toggle in Popover

Tags: jquery, html

I already can hide/show or toggle elements such as this one

```
<h4 id="h4">Hide this when needed</h4>
<button id="showInput" >Show Input</button>
<button id="hideTheH4">Hide Text</button>
<div id="input" style="display:none;">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>
```

And the scripts are

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#showInput').click(function(){
    $('#input').toggle();
  })
});
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#hideTheH4').click(function(){
    $('#h4').toggle();
  })
});
```

I saw this one http://jsfiddle.net/7ekRN/ and I tried to create a button with popover and button that can use script
This is the code

HTML

```
<h4 id="h4">Hide this when needed</h4>
<button data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" id="option">Option</button>

<div id="popOptions" style="display:none;">  
            <a href='#' id="showInput">Show Input</a><br>
            <a href='#' id="hideH4">Hide Text</a>
</div>
<div id="input" style="display:none;">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#option').popover({title: "Select", content: $("#popOptions").html(), html: true, placement: "right"}).click(function(){
     $(this).popover('show');
   });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#showInput').click(function(){
    $('#input').toggle();
  })
});
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#hideH4').click(function(){
    $('#h4').toggle();
  })
});
```

But when I click the contents of the Popover it doesn't toggle the H4 and Input

Do they have different?, Coz I don't know where or what is wrong

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: When I click the content of popover it does not toggle the div of id=h4 and id=input

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The only issue is that you have to include the `popover.js` library file to your script like this

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3rcepr0/) with your given code. I just included the `popover.js` library

Comment: Didnt work. Btw I used this code 

    <script >
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
    </script>`